# writing from one form to another based off of selected items

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to send selected item of this form to another form currently i was trying to use an accumulator but i have tried other things. my main form that i need to send things to is the frmshoppingcart.lstproductselected.text this is from my print books form but i have another form with audio books which has the same issue since it is pretty much identical code

```
Public Class frmPrintBooks
    Private Sub btnClose_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnClose.Click
        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Private Sub btnAddBooks_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddBooks.Click
        ' Declare Variables and Constants
        Dim decSubtotal As Decimal
        Dim decTax As Decimal
        Dim decShipping As Decimal
        Dim decTotal As Decimal
        Const decTaxTotal As Decimal = 0.6D
        Const decShippingRate As Decimal = 2D

        If lstPrintBooks.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
            decSubtotal = CDec(11.95)
            decTax = CDec(11.95 * decTaxTotal)
            decShipping = decShippingRate * 1
            decTotal = decSubtotal + decTax + decShipping
            Dim temp As String
            temp = lstPrintBooks.SelectedItem.text
            frmShoppingCart.lstProductsSelected.Text = temp


        ElseIf lstPrintBooks.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
            decSubtotal = CDec(14.5)
            decTax = CDec(14.5 * decTaxTotal)
            decShipping = decShippingRate * 1
            decTotal = decSubtotal + decTax + decShipping
        ElseIf lstPrintBooks.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
            decSubtotal = CDec(29.95)
            decTax = CDec(29.95 * decTaxTotal)
            decShipping = decShippingRate * 1
            decTotal = decSubtotal + decTax + decShipping
        ElseIf lstPrintBooks.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
            decSubtotal = CDec(18.5)
            decTax = CDec(18.5 * decTaxTotal)
            decShipping = decShippingRate * 1
            decTotal = decSubtotal + decTax + decShipping
        End If
        ' Show total due

        frmShoppingCart.txtSubtotal.Text = decSubtotal.ToString("c")
        frmShoppingCart.txtTax.Text = decTax.ToString("c")
        frmShoppingCart.txtShipping.Text = decShippingRate.ToString("c")
        frmShoppingCart.txtTotal.Text = decTotal.ToString("c")

    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the forms? Does the shopping cart form create and display the print books form? If so, is it displayed as a modal dialogue or not?

Comment: from a menu strip the shopping cart form displays the print book modal form.

Comment: In that case, there's no reason for the print books form to know anything about the shopping cart form. It shouldn't even know that it exists. The dialogue should simply make its data available publicly via one or more properties and, when it closes, expose a `DialogResult` of `OK` or `Cancel`. That `DialogResult` is returned by the `ShowDialog` method and, if it's `OK`, the shopping cart from retrieves the data from that property(ies) and updates itself.. This is how you should ALWAYS attempt to operate, i.e. only one side of the communication knows about the other.